# Cabal and --no-require-sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

In my `~/.cabal/config` file, I have

```
require-sandbox: True
```

According to the Cabal User Guide, I should be able to override this like so:

```
amy@wombat$ cabal install xmonad xmonad-contrib --no-require-sandbox
cabal: unrecognized 'install' option `--no-require-sandbox'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using cabal-install version 1.21.0.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cabal-install` is sensitive to the ordering of the command line flags respective to the subcommands. `--no-require-sanbox` is a *global* flag that applies to all subcommands, not just to `install`, so you need to put it before `install`:

```
$ cabal --no-require-sandbox install ...
```